# What is ROM (Read Only Memory)?

Tags: storage, rewrite, rom

If ROM is non-volatile memory, that means it can not be erased, rewritten, or modified. Then why can data, e.g. a song or photo, in a phone having 64GB ROM, be deleted or replaced with new data?

Comment: That is just a misleading term used by phone makers. There are two storage systems in such a mobile phone, just as your PC has memory and disk storage, but the ROM is certainly not read-only. Moreover, this is not a question about Ubuntu.

Comment: [Non-volatile memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory) does _not_ mean “it can not be erased, rewritten, or modified”. It means that the stored data survive a power outage unlike those stored in volatile memory, e.g. RAM.

Answer (score 4):

Because what people call nowadays ROM ("Read Only Memory") is almost always actually an EEPROM (Electrically Erasable and Programmable ROM).

The actual ROMs from the old days (containing eg. BIOSes of old PCs) were pre-written during manufacturing and could not be changed in any way (just like music CDs you buy in the shop).

There were also "empty" ROMs, called PROMs (Programmable ROMs), that could be written (only once, like CD-Rs) using a special device - ROM programmer.

Next step in ROM technology was EPROM (Erasable and Programmable ROM). Contents of EPROM could be erased by exposing the EPROM chip to ultraviolet light (EPROM chips had special window in the casing to allow the UV light get in), then EPROM could be written again in the same way as PROM.

And then came the EEPROMs, that can be re-written multiple times while still sitting in the computer, without the need to use any additional devices.

As today there are almost no ROMs other than EEPROMs, people started just using the term "ROM" for an EEPROM.

Comment: I would upvote except for the erroneous *"today there are almost no ROMs"*.  There are ROMs, but it's typically not user code since it's not going to change.  Typically an SoC  has a ROM (contents are masked during fabrication) for first-stage booting and perhaps a low-level maintenance console.  In technical documents, the term ROM is still used correctly.  It's phone and tablet marketing (and end-users) that abuse the acronym.

Answer (score 1):

Today, "ROM" is a misnomer. Just a historical name.
As you've said in your question, it is in fact "non volatile" rather than "read-only"

Same as today tar isn't used for Tape Archives.